# iOS custom animation inside UITabBarItem

Tags: ios, swift, animation

In our app we have a custom alert notification that is basically a circle within the `UITabBarItem`. I have added it by getting the view of `UITabBarItem` and then creating a `CAShapeLayer` in an appropriate position.  Unfortunately, no matter what I try I cannot get the shape to animate.  I've tried animating various properties such as path and fillColor with no success.

Here's a code excerpt:

```
var lyrShape = CAShapeLayer()
lyrShape.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
lyrShape.path = UIBezierPath(overIn: CGRect(x: 5, y: 5, width: 10, height: 10)).cgPath

vwTabBar.layer.addSublayer(lyrShape)

var aniShape = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "fillColor")
aniShape.duration = 5
aniShape.toValue = UIColor.blue.cgColor
aniShape.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn)
aniShape.fillMode = kCAFillModeBoth
aniShape.autoreverses = true
aniShape.repeatCount = 20

lyrShape.add(aniShape, forKey: aniShape.keyPath)
```

I've tried this code in regular views and it works great, however no matter what I try I can't get it working in the `UITabBarItem`.

UPDATE:  I have figured out the exact steps to reproduce this bug.  Start your app off with a plain old view controller with a button.  On that button click, present the tab controller view.  The shapes you draw in the TabBarItem will not animate at this point.  HOWEVER:  If the TabBarController is started as the first view, the animation happens just fine.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First of all I will say you asked a good question. I was even looking for something similar and I got my answer. You need to make a **custom class of UITabBarController** and then you can do something as below :

```
override func tabBar(tabBar: UITabBar, didSelectItem item: UITabBarItem) {
    if item.tag == 1{
    //do our animations
        self.secondItemImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.7, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .CurveEaseInOut, animations: { () -> Void in
            let rotation = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI_2))
            self.secondItemImageView.transform = rotation
        }, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

I got this answer form a blog post I was reading recently. For further clarity of this I would recommend you to refer this blog:
https://medium.com/@werry_paxman/bring-your-uitabbar-to-life-animating-uitabbaritem-images-with-swift-and-coregraphics-d3be75eb8d4d

I hope this will help you :)

Comment: Hi!  Thanks for the quick response.  HOWEVER:  I see no reason why you need to inherit from UITabBarController to accomplish this.  What does it change?  Also:  I'm not looking to animate an image.  Rather I am looking to  animate a CAShapeLayer inside of the UITabBarItem that I have added.

Can you explain why inheriting from UITabBarController works?  And why when you don't it doesn't?

Thanks!

Comment: I guess because we can not iterate the subviews of tabbar and nor we have access to the imageview property either directly. Subclassing gives you the flexibility to add your customised code and behaviour.

Comment: Actually you can get at the view of a UITabBarItem in a few different ways.  He even shows a really hacky way in his post to get the UIImage.  I iterate and test for views of a certain type, but you can certainly get at the view either way...  Thanks again for getting back to me.  I appreciate the input!

Answer (score 1):

So I finally heard back from Apple after I submitted a bug report.  They told me what I was doing was not supported, and that they weren't going to fix it.  Not exactly the answer I was looking for, but at least its an answer.

Hope this helps others out there who run into this too.

James